# How do I execute Flask on AWS EC2 instance?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-ec2

I have a Python script up and running on a AWS EC2 Ubuntu instance. I have installed Flask on the instance by following [this blog](https://medium.com/@jQN/deploy-a-flask-app-on-aws-ec2-1850ae4b0d41).

This is my basic flask app:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
  return 'Hello from Flask!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run()
```

I want a method that works on AWS EC2 Ubuntu environment for the above mentioned. I am only a beginner, so I request anyone who answers to be detailed.

Comment: What is _exactly_ is your question/problem? _Where_ did you got stuck? Did you already had a look into other blog posts like [this](https://www.codementor.io/dushyantbgs/deploying-a-flask-application-to-aws-gnva38cf0) or [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/deploying-a-python-web-app-on-aws-57ed772b2319)? Are you using a 'raw' EC2 instance or AWS Elastic Beanstalk in addition? Are you able to run your Flask app as desired on your local computer?

Comment: I am using a raw EC2 instance. I have both my flask script that shows 'hello world' and my other python script  (twinkle.py)  which i want to execute within my  flask script on my instance. They both work absolutely fine individualy both on ec2 and my local machine. Basically I need a way to print the output of twinkle.py on the web browser! @albert

Comment: Basically, you need to import your module inside your Flask application, call the desired functions from within flask and return the results as a response to the browser. For a primer on importing modules, have a look at [this](https://realpython.com/python-modules-packages/) and [this](https://realpython.com/absolute-vs-relative-python-imports/) blog post.

Answer (score 0):

You can host the flask app on AWS using Elastic Beanstalk service of AWS instead of trying to make the flask app work on an EC2 instance directly by running the flask app manually. By doing it this way, your app would get hosted on a public URL so that you can access it anytime.

For more details on how to host a flask application on AWS, refer the below link:

[Hosting a flask app on AWS Elastic Beanstalk](https://github.com/kmrambo/Deploying-a-Flask-or-Dash-application-using-AWS-Elastic-Beanstalk)